# How to view the value of a variable in Firefox Developer Edition 52.0a2?

Tags: javascript, firefox-developer-tools, javascript-debugger

In the Debugger in Firefox Developer Edition I've set a breakpoint to land on the assignment to a JavaScript variable. I expected to be able to hover over all previously defined variables to view their values within a tooltip like in previous versions of Firefox, but it doesn't show me anything and there doesn't seem to be a window I can add to the side:

[image: Debugger UI in Firefox Developer Edition 52.0a2]

Any ideas how to display the variable values?

Answer (score 5):

As described in an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40820036/432681), the *Debugger* panel in the Firefox Developer Edition 52.0a2 was actually an [external project reworked from scratch](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html), which didn't have all features of the original *Debugger* panel at that point in time.

This feature was [not implemented in that version yet](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html/issues/1574).

In that version, you had to look at the side panel under *Scopes* to see the variable value.

[image: Variable values in Debugger UI in Firefox 52.0a2]

In newer versions of Firefox, this feature is available by default. Though back then you could have switched to the old UI by setting the preference `devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend` in [about:config](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox) to `false` to get that feature back.

Comment: Does this answer need to be updated?

Comment: I've rephrased it, thanks!